# Audio DC Offset

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, dc-offset

I want to make an audio processing device using a Teensy and I want to run an analog signal into it. My background is in audio programming, so electronic circuits are new to me. I realise audio is an AC signal and the Teensy only accepts 0-5V signals. So my current exercise is to use a DC offset circuit to shift my AC signal into the 0-5V range.

Currently I am using a line-out from my phone using a mono 1/8 inch jack.  As the signal from my phone is weak (200 mV) have to amplify the analogue signal from my phone using the LM386. The circuit I used was a non-inverting amplifier (Figure 1). Resistor values I used were 1k for R2, and 10 Ohm for R1 (figures 2, 3, 4).

[image: Figure 1: non-inverting amplifier schematic]
[image: Figure 2: Fritzing illustration]
[image: Figure 3: My circuit]
[image: Figure 4: My circuit]

This works - I go from 180 mV to 2.5 Volts. In reality my signal fluctuates from 180 mV to 310 mV, and once amplified it fluctuates between 2.4 and 3.15 Volts. Is this to be expected, and is this acceptable to work with?

The next step is to do the DC offset which I am struggling to understand. I have read that a summing amplifier circuit can be used to add a DC signal to my AC signal to achieve the DC offset (Figure 5). Is this correct?

[image: Figure 5: non-inverting summing amplifier]

Does the extra DC voltage have to come from a separate voltage source? (i.e. not the battery that powers my op-amp) 
If so, why, and what should I use as my voltage source?

I have read forum posts on the topic, but the concept of adding extra voltages to an existing circuit is new to me and I wonder what the correct way to do it would be, does the extra voltage need to be grounded to the same ground?

Thank you for your time. :)

Maria

Comment: [2 resistors and a capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221638/biasing-an-ac-voltage-for-input-to-adc) would solve your problem.

Comment: The LM386 is **not** an opamp.  It will not work as an opamp.  It is an audio amplifier. It is intended to amplify by a specific amount, and to drive a speaker.  You may be able to use it for your task, but it will be easier if you get an opamp and use it properly.